# How to keep inline 2 fixed elements having min-width?

Tags: css, css-position

There are 2 fixed(can't be change) inline blocks and min-widths for both of them. When i'm trying to resize the window (width less then min) they overlap each other. Any suggestion ? How can I set min-width for whole page?

```
<div style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;width:40%;min-width:500px;border:2px solid red;margin:5px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="position:fixed;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;width:40%;min-width:500px;border:2px solid blue;margin:5px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: The elements are being positioned absolutely with `fixed` value which causes the elements position relative to the initial containing block (therefore, the viewport). So, no it's not possible unless you change that value with `absolute`, etc. and give the element whose establishing a containing block a `min-width` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **no**, not without changing that `position: fixed`

have a look at what `position: fixed` actually means:

> fixed
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position **relative to the screen's viewport** and don't move it
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

And since you can't control the width of the viewport...

Position absolute should work though, and then you can set your body to something like this:

```
body {
    min-width: 1020px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
html{
  height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1forkath/